# adding files to heroku app with a database addon in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord.js

I'm hosting my discord bot on heroku and i installed this database for adding files, because for what i understood heroku has a temporarly file system, and also things like fs don't work anymore. This is the addon i installed: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql

Here is an example of the code i used for appending to txts/json files:

```
// Json example

if (command === 'jsonExample') {

config.example = args[0]
var stringifiedConfig = JSON.stringify(config, null, 4);

fs.writeFileSync("./config.json", stringifiedConfig)
console.log(stringifiedConfig)

}

// Txt example

if (command === 'txtExample') {

fs.appendFileSync('folder/example.txt', data + "\r\n", (err) => {

if (err) throw (err)
 
        }) 
}
console.log('File edited')
```

The thing is i don't know how i could adapt it to work with the database, i'm very new to heroku and i didn't really find anything for discord bots, i hope you can help.

Answer (score 1):

[PostgresSQL](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql) is a cloud SQL database. You use HTTP requests to talk to the API to upload/download files/data from the database.

PostgresSQL has a [Node.js package](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-node-js), [`pg`](https://npmjs.com/package/pg), which you use to interact with the database.

Using this database, your provided code might look like this:

```js
const { Client } = require("pg"),
  client = new Client({
    // make sure you set your environment variables in the heroku dashboard
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
  });

client.connect();

async function commandCode(command, config, args, data) {
  if (command === "jsonExample") {
    config.example = args[0];
    const stringifiedConfig = JSON.stringify(config);
    await client.query(/* some SQL query here */);
    console.log(stringifiedConfig);
  } else if (command === "txtExample") {
    await client.query(/* some SQL query here */);
    console.log("File edited.");
  }
}
```

You will need to know how to use SQL to use this database, which may or may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: Is there some other good database maybe easier to use? i really never used sql or databases in general so i don't know much about it, sorry, but if postgres is one of the best i can learn sql. Anyway considering i already have a client const for the bot, `const client = new Discord.Client()`, should i have to rename `const { Client } = require("pg")` for not causing problems? If there will be any of course